# Is there a possibility to corrupt a Windows Registry for repeated update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, batch-file

I created a C++ program that runs in start up to call a `.bat` script that I created during log-in in my pc (Windows 10). Basically what the script does when it detects an internet connection it updates the registry with a registry file I exported and else it applies a different registry settings if no internet connection detected.

I'm thinking if it do updates everytime I logon is there a possibility that I corrupt the registry or crash the system?

I just want to avoid that.

Comment: So what registry setting are you changing exactly and you want to know what about it again exactly?

Comment: Windows Policy settings. It's just actually a wallpaper configuration under `Current User>Microsoft>Windows>Current Version>Policy`. When it detects an internet connection it applies a different wallpaper and when it's not it applies a different wallpaper. What I'm asking is does it trigger corruption of entire registry for repeated update every login? or Does it have a higher risk to be corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we just change the registry keys in HKCU, it will not lead to big issue, maybe your current account will meet with some unexcepted conditions but whole system will not be broken down.

Besides, you could use Computer Startup Scripts to execute your .bat script.